# Syntax Error in MySQL Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, errors

I facing the issue in executing a SQL Stored Procedure and I got the error message as showing syntax error in my statement, but I couldn't find that,

### Stored Procedure

---

-- Routine DDL
-- Note: comments before and after the routine body will not be stored by the server

---

DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `enterprisedb`.`orderstatus`

(
    IN   inmode             varchar(27),
    IN   OrderStatus_id     int,
    IN   Status_comments    varchar(255),
    IN   CreatedOn          datetime,
    IN   CreatedBy          varchar(255),
    IN   UpdatedOn          datetime,
    IN   UpdatedBy          varchar(255),
    IN   is_active          bit
)

BEGIN

`/*insert*/
if inmode   =   'insert'
then
    insert into orderstatus
    (OrderStatus_id, OrderStatus, Status_comments, CreatedOn, CreatedBy, UpdatedOn, UpdatedBy, is_active)
    values
    (OrderStatus_id, OrderStatus, Status_comments, CreatedOn, CreatedBy, UpdatedOn, UpdatedBy, is_active);
end if;

/*update*/
if inmode   =   'update'
then
    update orderstatus ods
    set
    ods.OrderStatus         =   OrderStatus,
    ods.Status_comments     =   Status_comments,
    ods.CreatedOn           =   CreatedOn,
    ods.CreatedBy           =   CreatedBy,
    ods.UpdatedOn           =   UpdatedOn,
    ods.UpdatedBy           =   UpdatedBy,
    ods.is_active           =   is_active
    where
    ods.OrderStatus_id      =   OrderStatus_id;

/*delete*/
if inmode   =   'delete'
then
    update orderstatus ods
    set
    ods.is_active           =   0
    where
    ods.OrderStatu_id       =   OrderStatus_id;
end if;

/*select*/
if inmode   =   'select'
then
    select * from orderstatus ods
    where
    ods.OrderStatus_id      =   OrderStatus_id;
end if; END`

It displays the following messages,I couldn't find the error.

[image]

1. Can I click on the Yes button and continue with procedure?
2. Will it cause any issue?
3. How to solve this? a
   A
   Any suggestions, answers and comments are welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you perhaps missing an "end if;" from the "if inmode = 'delete'" statement?